# replace string java Scanner class

Tags: java, regex, string, substring

```
import java.util.*;
public class ReplaceString {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ReplaceString().run();
    }

    public void run()
    {

        System.out.println("Input String:\n");
        Scanner keyboardScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String inString = keyboardScanner.nextLine();
        String strOutput = inString.replace("is","was");
        System.out.println(strOutput);      

    }
}
```

I am trying to replace all  occurences of "is" with "was" from an inputted line, which I was able to do but I do not want to mess the words where "is" is a part of the word.

For example any occurence of word nameis or this should be ignored. Only individual occurences of "is" should be replace with "was"

I know I can use regular expressions but i dont know the format if that regex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
 String strOutput = inString.replaceAll("\\bis\\b","was");
```

[reference link](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/bounds.html)

Test output:

```
Input String:

is island is feris kiss
```

output

```
was island was feris kiss
```

Comment: What if `is` occurs at the beginning of the input? What about an input of `island`?

Comment: @Mark it seems to be fine for the test cases you mention.

Comment: The trailing `\\b` wasn't there when I commented, now I agree, +1

Comment: what does  \\bis\\b indicate, i know b is the boundary value

Answer (score 0):

not that i know much with java, but you can try adding spaces. Theoretically that should work.

```
System.out.println("Input String:\n");
Scanner keyboardScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String inString = keyboardScanner.nextLine();
String strOutput = inString.replace(" is "," was ");
System.out.println(strOutput);
```

Comment: What if `is` occurs at the beginning or the end of the input?

Comment: i tried that already before posting the question but then what if the first occurence of the sentence is "is" with no space before it. In that case this first occurence3 is never replace because it does not match "is "